# C++ / Pass by value results in #DEN

Tags: c++, visual-studio-debugging, pass-by-value

Debugging some code with Visual Studio and I was surprised to find that the values of the property of an object looked great before the call into a method and then were corrupted as soon as I entered the method:

The call comes from here.  The debugger reports that `thingA.property = 0.14`

```
method1()
{
  Thing thingA;

  object.method2(thingA)
}
```

and goes into here and the debugger reports `thingMine.property = 4.0E-315#DEN`

```
method2(Thing thingMine)
{
....
}
```

When I change scope back up to `method1` the property looks fine and scoping back down to `method2` the property takes on a wildly different value.

What can cause the value to change?  Back in the *old days* with C, I can mangle memory by fooling around with pointers.  However, there's nothing fancy about this code.  There are no (explicit) pointers.  The compiler is happy with the cast / class of all the objects.  There is no fancy inheritance or overloading.

To add more detail, `Thing` is not simply a class with properties and methods.  Its properties are objects, but still not very fancy:

```
class Thing {
public:
  AnotherThing thingInsideAThing;
...
}
```

It is the property of `AnotherThing` that is getting mangled.

My understand of *pass-by-value* is based upon my ancient schooling in C.  I thought calling a method would push an explicit copy of `thingA` onto the stack.  Does it push a bad address for `thingA.object` onto the stack?  I thought *pass-by-value* was **always** the safest way to forward information into a method.

Where do I begin to understand the underlying problem?

Comment: Without actually seeing the real code for `Thing` or `AnotherThing`, I can only surmise that there is faulty logic in the copy constructor of `Thing`, which gets called when passing `thingA` to `method2()` by value

Comment: I did not make a copy constructor.  How do I know when I can rely upon the compiler to do this and when I need to do it myself?  There are no explicit pointers in the definition of the class.  There are only standard types (double, int) and objects from classes I defined myself.

Comment: Without a [mcve], there is no way for anyone here to diagnose the problem

Comment: The general comments are enough to direct me to create the example.  I'll work on it today.

Comment: Sadly, my minimal code does *not* exhibit the bug.  Pass-by-value and pass-by-ref both work just fine in my test code.  This leaves me wondering how I reproduce this problem.

Comment: I didn't flag this for moderation. But soliciting suggestions is not what StackOverflow is meant for.  SO is a Q+A site, it deals in *specific* questions that can be answered. If you can't provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue, noone here can diagnose it and offer an explanation or fix. So, you will have to keep debugging on your own. Short of a compiler bug in codegen, it has to be a coding bug. Check your constructors and assignment operators, make sure everything works as expected, are not doing shallow copies where deep copies are needed, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is found in the way that Visual Studio displays values for objects that are

- pass by value
- pass by constant reference

The code below assigns the proper value to `a`.  However, for my object, the debugger reports `#DEN` when I ask it to display `thing.x`.

```
method(Thing thing)
  {
    double a = thing.x;
  }
```

However, when I write:

```
method(const Thing& thing)
  {
    double a = thing.x;
  }
```

the debugger reports the expected value for `thing.x`.

I recognize that there is a difference between *pass by value* and *pass by constant reference*.  However, in my case I don't think that there is a practical difference.